# Автоматический показ количества новых/измененных вопросов

Tags: поддержка

Сегодня после моего обеда (!) страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ перестала автоматически показывать количество новых/измененных вопросов - серенькая полосочка над самым первым вопросом и счетчик в заголовке страницы. Мне это очень нравилось. Это конфигурируемо?

Comment: Видимо, зависит от того, чем Вы обедали.

Comment: @alexolut Я готов вообще больше не обедать, если это поможет.

Comment: На самом деле, может быть просто отвалился интернет :)

Comment: @alexolut А с Вами я сейчас по трубе разговариваю?

Comment: она до сих не показывает?

Comment: @alexolut да, и дома тоже

Comment: У меня тоже оно не пашет сегодня (Yandex Browser, win 7)

Comment: Тогда, скорее всего, это баг. Возможно, связанный со шляпами.

Comment: "Живая шляпа". Дело в том, что на англоязычном SO этот счетчик у меня никогда не показывался, и я тихо радовался, как это хорошо на ruSO - когда браузер минимизирован в TaskBar, a в заголовке видно, есть ли что-то новое. Еще удивлялся, какие молодцы по сравнению с GMail'ом, что вынесли эту инфомацию в самое начало заголовка.

Comment: Видимо из-за того, что это теперь вкладка "Интересный", которая показывает не последние обновленные вопросы, а что-то другое.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6542/178988 - не оно?

Comment: VadimTagil, Qwertiy - да, оно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, этот функционал переехал с главной страницы на страницу вопросов:

> [image: новая активность]

Comment: Спасибо. Снова можно обедать.

Comment: @Igor приятного аппетита!