# Новая вкладка «интересные»

Tags: поддержка

С радостью спешу сообщить, что с сегодняшнего дня на Stack Overflow на русском сортировкой на главной странице становится «[интересные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)»!

#### В чем основная идея?

Чтобы сделать выборку вопросов на главной более интересной для конкретного участника, мы решили отказаться от сортировки по последней активности, которую мы определяем как новый ответ, правка или новый вопрос. Сортировка «интересные вопросы», в свою очередь, использует последние 400 активных вопросов и:

- исключает вопросы с игнорируемыми вами метками;
- исключает закрытые вопросы, если у вас недостаточно репутации для голоса за повторное открытие;
- исключает вопросы с рейтингом -4 и менее.

Далее вычисляется несложная формула для поиска коэффициента для каждого вопроса:

- на основе интересующих вас меток: +1500 на каждую метку, максимум +2000 в сумме;
- ваши лучшие 40 меток на основе полученной репутации по метке: максимум +1000 за метку, максимум +2000 в сумме;
- рейтинг вопроса: +200 × рейтинг, максимум +1000 в сумме;
- суммарный рейтинг ответов: -200 × рейтинг, максимум -1000 в сумме;
- количество ответов: -200 × количество, максимум -1000 в сумме;
- количество просмотров: -15 × количество, максимум -1000 в сумме;
- последняя активность в вопросе: -1 × (секунды / 15).

Подсчитываем и выбираем 90 вопросов с наивысшим коэффициентом.

Дополнительно в выборку попадают 10% (9 вопросов) случайно выбранных вопросов из 400 для авторизованных участников и 20% (18 вопросов) для анонимных пользователей.

Старая «главная вкладка» также доступна по прямой ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active

Общая идея также описана в блоге в публикации «[Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)».

*Буду крайне рад услышать ваш отзыв!*

Comment: А вкладка-то называется «интересный» ))

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! Уже поправил, в ближайшее время будет на сайте!

Comment: Я так понимаю, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=active по-прежнему работает, просто ссылка с сайта скрыта? У меня индивидуальная непереносимость «умных лент», хотелось бы чтоб «текущие» тоже продолжали работать

Comment: @andreymal совершенно верно, выборка работает по прямой ссылке как и ранее.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "текущие" не планируется вернуть в табы или только по ссылке можно будет открывать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Как я понимаю, нет. Ссылка работать будет, но самой сортировки в интерфейсе пользователя не будет.

Comment: Т.е. выбора пользователю дать нельзя, какой вариант ему более предпочтителен?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov В текущей версии, на сколько я понимаю, нет. [Была инициатива по динамической настройке сортировок](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/), правда, на сколько я знаю, еще в итоге откатили.

Comment: А настройка чтобы вернуть как раньше на логотип будет? Ну и табу вернуть.

Comment: Исключение вопросов с игнорируемыми метками - это отлично!

Comment: Откровенно говоря, выдало список, в котором в основном вопросы на совершенно не интересующие темы... Из всего списка 26 вопросов (и то в основном внизу) с интересующими меня тэгами. Наверное, нужно активнее использовать игнорируемые метки...

Comment: @Harry где–то в коде, на сколько я могу понимать, должен быть реализован какой–то обучаемый алгоритм. Надеюсь со временем качество выдачи улучшиться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky почему то теперь отображается вкладка "новые" это тоже что и "интересные" ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Сортировка «интересные вопросы» доступна только на главной, но не в разделе «вопросы» (/questions/), если я правильно понял контекст вопроса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Точно, не обратил внимания, что зашел в "вопросы". Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Верните, пожалуйста, старую вкладку в интерфейс. Пусть будут обе вкладки, но заменять одну другой не нужно.

Отвратительная общемировая тенденция решать за пользователя, что ему интересно, а что нет.

Comment: Прежнее поведение [доступно на вкладке вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6546/176217).

Comment: Не очень удобно (лишний клик), но спасибо!

Comment: сделайте закладку на эту страницу браузере, и начинайте с неё.

Comment: @alexolut, поведение прежнее, а страница другая - на главной была фильтрация, а на вопросах её нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy пишите FR на MSE :)

Comment: @alexolut, фр-фр-фр на mSE :D