# Устраивает ли нас как работает вкладка «интересные» вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

В середине декабря мы [добавили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6542/) новую выборку «интересные» на главную страницу. Вкладка «интересные» добавляется на сайт, если на нем публикуется много вопросов, и найти что–то интересное, чтобы ответить, получается не сразу. Вкладка «интересные» призвана решить эту проблему и на основе истории использования сайта участником, предложить ему вопросы, в которых участник сможет проявить себя.

Вкладка активна на сайте уже более двух месяцев, и многие из участников скорее всего сформировали свое мнение о ней, поняли что им не нравится, что нравится.

**Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашим опытом с другими участниками!**

Расскажите ваши «за» и «против». На основе отзывов в этом вопросе мы попробуем понять нужно и можно ли нам что–то улучшить и стоит ли вернуть выборку «активные» назад на главную.

Comment: не хватает автоматической плашки - обновлено столько-то.

Comment: Возможно это только у меня такая реакция, но сообщения с метками на которые я подписан выделяются красным цветом, но у меня красный цвет ассоциируется со "стоп не ходи", возможно зеленоватый цвет будет уместнее.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин У меня светло-бежевый, и он для меня комфортен

Comment: Кроме того, что отметил @Grundy, не хватает "показать только те сообщения, которые содержат интересные вам теги"

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин красным? Ни разу такого не видел. Скриншот можно посмотреть?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov метки, которые добавлены в избранное? Или какие «теги» Вам интересны?

Comment: @alexolut я выразился неточно, тут скорее розовый, но он у меня где-то идёт как оттенок красного, а значит "стоп".

Comment: @alexolut Идеально: и то, и то, с переключением

Comment: Никогда этой плашки не видел, так как она есть только на главной, а в вопросах нет.

Answer (score 9):

Мне не хватает автоматического обновления. Я обычно смотрю вопросы на главной странице, но в новом исполнении главная страница не самообновляется.

Я бы предложил не возвращаться к старой странице (в конце-концов, хорошая сортировка лучше плохой), а прикрутить к новой автоматический показ количества новых вопросов (как это было на старой).

Comment: Сортировка «интересные» пришла к нам как функция англоязычного сообщества, где такой проблемы просто нет (так как вопросов очень много). Я общался с коллегами, они ответили, что вроде бы подобного обновления нет в планах. Чтобы убедить ответственных коллег, мне необходимы серьезные обоснования и доводы. Было бы здорово, если бы вы помогли развернутой мыслью, как именно оно должно работать и почему сейчас отсутствие реализации доставляет много проблем.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Хм, а что для них серьёзное обоснование? То, что фичу нельзя использовать в небольшом  комьюнити (причём проблема, судя по всему, не только на ru.SO, а и у других, англоязычных сайтов) — это обоснование?

Comment: Узнаем. Чем больше доводов у меня есть, тем больше вероятность склонить коллег на нашу сторону. Просто «нам надо» никогда не работало в компании, если честно. Всех надо убедить в необходимости данной функции: от коллег по команде, до конечных разработчиков. Буду признателен, если вы поможете мне с доводами, почему эта функция нужна и важна для нашего сообщества, почему без нее никак.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Я могу говорить лишь для чего она _мне_. А это просто: я вижу на ней свежие вопросы, на которые можно ответить. То есть я оставляю страницу открытой в неактивной вкладке, и когда вижу новые появившиеся вопросы (это бывает раз в пару минут), захожу и смотрю их. Каждый раз обновлять страницу неудобно: нужно переключиться из того, что я в данный момент делаю, в другую вкладку, обновить страницу, вспомнить, какие там были вопросы, и в большинстве случаев убедиться, что ничего не поменялось. Почему это работает на en.SO, я не представляю.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: ... разве что там в _любой_ момент можно обновить страницу и гарантированно найти подходящий вопрос. У нас это не так, подходящие вопросы появляются редко.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: «Без неё никак» было бы неправдой: вот сейчас же я как-то обхожусь? Ну отвечаю на меньшее количество вопросов, да, но это ж не является доводом для разработчиков?

Comment: Понял! Спасибо за пояснение! На мой взгляд, довод «меньше ответов» самый весомый, так как вкладку добавляли, чтобы их было больше, а не меньше.

Answer (score 6):

Что на enSO, что тут, главная страница мне вообще не нравится. Есть некоторое количество тегов, которые я просматриваю регулярно, все остальное меня мало интересует. О том, что вкладка "Интересные" сушествует, я узнал только вчера, когда прочитал этот вопрос. До этого даже внимания не обращал.
Я сейчас использую закладки в браузере, у меня есть кнопочка на панели, на которой написано "ruSO", и там прописана ссылка типа такой:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+or+oracle11g+or+<еще пару тегов>
```

У меня есть интересные для меня теги двух категорий: на одни я подписан (они справа отображаются) - это как бы первый уровень интересности, а часть из них перечислены в той ссылке, что в закладках браузера, - это второй уровень, их я вообще все время смотрю. 
А то, что сейчас на закладке "Интересные" - такое ощущение, что там просто все подряд навалено.

Что мне в поиске по тегам не нравится, это то, что там вопросы отсортированы по дате создания вопроса. Соответственно, если со старым вопросом что-то случится (какая-то новая активность), я этого скорее всего не увижу. На главной при этом вопросы сортируются по дате последней активности.

Меня устроил бы любой из двух вариантов: либо если сортировка будет по последней активности в вопросе при поиске по тегам, либо если "Интересные" будут содержать только вопросы с избранными тегами. Тогда будет просто идеально.

Comment: Допишите к своему URL в конце `?sort=active` — будет сортировка по дате последнего изменения. Также эта сортировка доступна на вкладке "текущие" (у вас, вероятно, активна вкладка "новые").

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Со времен enSO удивляет распределение вопросов на этой вкладке. Как они так подбираются, что все интересные (в т.ч. с моими метками) сосредоточены внизу?

Уже вошло в привычку, если не был на сайте пару дней, открывать "интересные" и сразу проматывать вниз - там все самое интересное.

Comment: Не могли бы вы как–то описать, что именно не так, то есть задать какие–то строгие критерии, на что смотреть, чтобы я мог провести анализ?

Answer (score 1):

Открываем страницу со всеми вопросами и смотрим, что нулей полно, а просмотров мало. Делаем вывод, что новый вариант главной ухудшил просматриваемость вопросов.

Comment: Не уверен, что по одному обновлению страницы можно сделать вывод. Более правильно будет воспользоваться [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).